# Hadoop: How do multiple map tasks ensure they're not competing fo resources?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I will have 3 **jobs running simultaneously** in Hadoop, they're unrelated.

The input to one of them is over HTTP, **slow downloads** of large files.

The others are **inputs from HDFS** and S3N filesystems.

I'm new to building this kind of thing in Hadoop.

- How do I optimize the map phase?
- It seems logical that I'd want a **disk read** to at least happen at the **same time** that a **download** is happening.
- I sure wouldn't want **all** the large **disk operations** to **wait on downloads** (each of 20 downloads could be an hour)
- I presume I don't want to have multiple, large, **disk reads** happening at the **same time**.

How is this this map/input/data-acquisition phase handled by Hadoop?

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. Just increase the number of map slots so your jobs can run in parallel while saturating your machine well.

Comment: haha, maybe I don't know what I'm talking about, that happens sometimes when you're new to things. I guess the concern is: if I have 10 HTTP map tasks, and 10 HDFS map tasks, isn't it possible that one box would have all the HTTP map tasks? I guess it's just luck of the draw which node gets various map tasks right? I am just trying to understand the process better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mapreduce usually all maps/reducers do the same job.

But you can achieve your goal with two different solutions:

1.Basically,  you should consider splitting your job on two independent jobs and then start them with specified number of tasks per node. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-5170 but this patch applied only on cdh, not base distribution.

2.Another option is to implement your own Input format, which will be able to encode operation for map and balance number of different tasks per node. This can be accomplished by specifying hosts in InputSplit for each split.